# spring boot integration test check Long id

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing

I am checking id after save process but it's giving error like that:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.id"
Expected: is <1L>
     but: was <1>
<Click to see difference>
```

I think error is because of Long and int comparison. I tried to convert int to long but I couldn't solve.

So here is my code:

```
@Test
    public void testGetBlogPostById_whenBlogPostIdExist_shouldReturnBlogPostDto() throws Exception {
        BlogPost blogPost = generateBlogPost(1L, "postName");
        blogPost = blogPostRepository.save(blogPost);

        this.mockMvc.perform(get(baseUrl + "/post/" + blogPost.getId())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(blogPost.getId())));
    }
```

Comment: what is the type returned $.id, can you check type  blogpost entity

Comment: in blogpost entity's getId() method's returns Long but when i get id from jsonPath("$.id"... it's returning integer.

Comment: You would want to try `blogPost.getId().intValue()`.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi very clear solution. It works thanks!

Comment: Have you tryed .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value("1"))

Comment: @MetinBulak I can't try because actually id value is setting from database.  But  ```blogPost.getId().intValue()``` worked for me. Thanks.